# Unable to start ASP Application using `dnx run` on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, mono, dnx, coreclr

I am on Ubuntu 14.04

I have installed ASP using these instructions http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html#installing-on-ubuntu-14-04

Running `dnvm list` gives me the following:

```
Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          linux           default
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono                 linux/osx
```

I then tried to create an ASP application using this tutorial:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-app-using-vscode/

However when I run `dnx run` I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IHostingBuilder.UseServer() is required for Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplication.Run(Type startupType, String[] args)
   at ASPTutorial.Startup.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteMain>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

A similar issue arises when I change from `coreclr` to `mono`.

**UPDATE**

`dnx web` works fine however!

Comment: How about `dnx web`?

Comment: That works! Why does `dnx run` not work???

Comment: `dnx run` is normally for running console apps.

Comment: `dnx run` is for console apps. BTW: You might want to look at using `dotnet`  cli as `dnx` is being retired ;-) https://github.com/dotnet/cli

Comment: I'm confused at to why the tutorial said to use `dnx run`. Also is `dotnet` cli officially maintained by Microsoft or a Community thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to run with dnx is defined in the project.json in your project.

As mentioned in the comments, "run" is usually used for console applications and "web" is used for web applications. But you can write any command name you want in your project.jseon, even something like:

```
"commands": {
    "runmyawesomeapp": "[...]"
}
```

And you can run it with

```
> dnx runmyawesomeapp
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: I see. But I'm surprised why the tutorial asked for `dnx run`, when there is no `run` command.

Comment: because it's microsoft